# What Drupal tables to export from broken site

Tags: 7, database, importing-exporting, log-messages

I'm on localhost with Acquia Dev Desktop , Drupal 7.34. Php 5.3.29.

I was just playing in the Views when suddenly the site crashed. After few `drush cc` and restart of Acquia Dev Desktop and trying to access the site again showed me:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate X bytes) in c:\sites*\database.inc on line 2171.

I tried to increase memory limit to 1024M in `php.ini` and `settings.php`. Then I check the PhpMyadmin and I found that the watchdog table has ~6,000,000 records and its 6.4GB so I deleted it. `drush cc`, disable statistics and `dblog` modules. But still can't access the site. it just don't open. I copy watchdog table from another Drupal install (actually it was a previous backup) but still doesn't work and now it shows:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds ...

and the watchdog db increased from 0mb to 350mb with ~777,034   rows.
Can I export certain tables with my views, taxonomy and settings and import them in another Drupal clean install? the Content is not important.

Edit:

> Watchdog Message:`%type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).`
>
> Variables: [BLOB - 294 B]
>
> location: http://nina2.dd:8083/
>
> the file watchdog_variables.bin says:

```
a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:14:"Strict warning";s:8:"!message";s:40:"Creating default object from empty value";s:9:"%function";s:43:"views_many_to_one_helper->ensure_my_table()";s:5:"%file";s:60:"C:\Sites\nina2\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc";s:5:"%line";i:940;s:14:"severity_level";i:7;}
```

Comment: What kinds of messages are you getting in the watchdog table?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the database table level, no.  There's a contributed module in Drupal called "Features" that lets you export content types, fields, views and some other configuration into a custom created module, but you would need a functioning site to begin using it.